# Is it possible to write an inconsistent Prolog program using only pure Prolog, cut and `false`?

Tags: prolog

This one tickled my interest in theory:

Is it possible to write an inconsistent Prolog program, i.e. a program that answers both *false* and *true* depending on how it is queried, using only pure Prolog, the cut, and `false`?

For example, one could query `p(1)` and the Prolog Processor would says `false`. But when one queries `p(X)` the Prolog Processor would give the set of answers `1`, `2`, `3`.

This can be easily achieved with "computational state examination predicates" like `var/1` (really better called `fresh/1`) + el cut:

```
p(X) :- nonvar(X),!,member(X,[2,3]).
p(X) :- member(X,[1,2,3]).
```

Then

```
?- p(1).
false.

?- p(X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3.
```

"Ouch time" ensues if this is high-assurance software. Naturally, any imperative program has no problem going off the rails like this on every other line.

So. can be done without those "computational state examination predicates"?

**P.S.**

The above illustrates that all the predicates of Prolog are really carrying a threaded hidden argument of the "computational state":

```
p(X,StateIn,StateOut).
```

which can be used to explain the behavour of `var/1` and friends. The Prolog program is then "pure" when it only calls predicates that neither consult not modify that `State`. Well, at least that seems to be a good way to look at what is going on. I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very simple one:

```
f(X,X) :- !, false.
f(0,1).
```

Then:

```
| ?- f(0,1).

yes
| ?- f(X,1).

no
| ?- f(0,Y).

no
```

So Prolog claims there are no solutions to the queries with variables, although `f(0,1)` is true and would be a solution to both.

Comment: Ah, but it's still consistent. The ground literals `f(0,1)`, `f(1,1)`, and `f(0,0)` are in the TRUE set (in additional to any `f(X,X)` of course). It's fine!

Comment: Yes! That's one.

Comment: That cut really transform the `f(X,X)` into a BLACKHOLE NEGATION: You will be negated and you can't leave! But somehow it feels counterintuitive that Prolog matches the `f(X,X)` head (general) before `f(0,1)` (peculiar).

Comment: Clauses for the same predicate are always tried in order. I think the single clause `f(X,Y) :- X=Y, !, false; X=0, Y=1.` would be entirely equivalent.

Comment: Yes, it would be.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one attempt. The basic idea is that `X` is a variable iff it can be unified with *both* `a` and `b`. But of course we can't write this as `X = a, X = b`. So we need a "unifiable" test that succeeds without binding variables like `=/2` does.

First, we need to define negation ourselves, since it's impure:

```
my_not(Goal) :-
    call(Goal),
    !,
    false.
my_not(_Goal).
```

This is only acceptable if your notion of pure Prolog includes `call/1`. Let's say that it does :-)

Now we can check for unifiability by using `=/2` and the "not not" pattern to preserve success while undoing bindings:

```
unifiable(X, Y) :-
    my_not(my_not(X = Y)).
```

Now we have the tools to define `var`/`nonvar` checks:

```
my_var(X) :-
    unifiable(X, a),
    unifiable(X, b).

my_nonvar(X) :-
    not(my_var(X)).
```

Let's check this:

```
?- my_var(X).
true.

?- my_var(1).
false.

?- my_var(a).
false.

?- my_var(f(X)).
false.

?- my_nonvar(X).
false.

?- my_nonvar(1).
true.

?- my_nonvar(a).
true.

?- my_nonvar(f(X)).
true.
```

The rest is just your definition:

```
p(X) :-
    my_nonvar(X),
    !,
    member(X, [2, 3]).
p(X) :-
    member(X, [1, 2, 3]).
```

Which gives:

```
?- p(X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3.

?- p(1).
false.
```

**Edit:** The use of `call/1` is not essential, and it's interesting to write out the solution without it:

```
not_unifiable(X, Y) :-
    X = Y,
    !,
    false.
not_unifiable(_X, _Y).

unifiable(X, Y) :-
    not_unifiable(X, Y),
    !,
    false.
unifiable(_X, _Y).
```

Look at those second clauses of each of these predicates. They are the same! Reading these clauses declaratively, *any two terms are not unifiable*, but also *any two terms are unifiable*! Of course you cannot read these clauses declaratively because of the cut. But I find this especially striking as an illustration of how catastrophically impure the cut is.

Comment: Isabelle, thank you. I accept aschepler's response because it's shorter.